# При попытке установить модули npm install не устанавливает их и выдает ошибку

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/macbookpro/.npm/_cacache/tmp/b3b4e5ce
npm ERR! dest /Users/macbookpro/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/91/11/682f7fb259505086c68494719f1e8281eb8d59d1fcb51428e275df45acc15382837a316ce87e24fc87949898f16f747a1886800d89645b91493eece3f6e8
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/set-function-length: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/Users/macbookpro/.npm/_cacache/tmp/b3b4e5ce' -> '/Users/macbookpro/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/91/11/682f7fb259505086c68494719f1e8281eb8d59d1fcb51428e275df45acc15382837a316ce87e24fc87949898f16f747a1886800d89645b91493eece3f6e8'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/macbookpro/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/91/11/682f7fb259505086c68494719f1e8281eb8d59d1fcb51428e275df45acc15382837a316ce87e24fc87949898f16f747a1886800d89645b91493eece3f6e8
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/macbookpro/.npm/_logs/2023-11-17T08_37_45_687Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: попробуйте вот это `sudo npm cache clean --force && npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Это выбивает, но сама нода уже установленна
ERROR
[eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/macbookpro/Projects/nft-project/node_modules/.cache'

Comment: вы использовали при установке библиотек sudo или другого пользователя?

Comment: sudo npm cache clean --force && npm cache clean --force

Я прописал эту команду и старая проблема пропала, а при самом билде выбивает эта проблема

Comment: это - ответ на мой последний вопрос?

Comment: Да, если я правильно понял

Comment: в корне проекта выполните `rm -rf node_modules`, потом `npm i`. и работайте всегда под одним, своим, пользователем

Comment: наверное, надежнее даже `sudo rm -rf node_modules` в корне проекта

Comment: Проблема была в package-lock, спасибо за помощь

Comment: `EACCES: permission denied` это проблема с доступом к ресурсу на диске, а не "была в package-lock"